# importing csv in pandas but losing date format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm importing a csv using Pandas but losing my date format from 03052018 -> 3052018.  From researching, it needs to be imported as a string to not lose the beginning '0'.

I've tried
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str)

but I'm getting error:
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type:

Completely stumped.....

```
actual = pd.read_csv(actuals, dtype=str)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-c7cfc919d72d> in <module>
      1 data = pd.read_csv(file)
----> 2 actual = pd.read_csv(actuals, dtype=str)

S:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

S:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    429     # See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1297
    430     fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
--> 431         filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
    432     )
    433     kwds["compression"] = compression

S:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode)
    198     if not is_file_like(filepath_or_buffer):
    199         msg = f"Invalid file path or buffer object type: {type(filepath_or_buffer)}"
--> 200         raise ValueError(msg)
    201 
    202     return filepath_or_buffer, None, compression, False

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Edit:  By using 'str' vs str plus retyping the file path, it now seems to be working as intended.  Much appreciated.

Comment: What's `file`, how are you loading it? These are important information as your error is telling you the file path is an issue.  Please see [ask] and [edit] your question.   As it stands your question have no relevance to losing date formats.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, the dtype specifier needs to be a string itself.  Using a simple test.csv file containing:

```
date,value
03052018,22
11142019,32
16022020,55
```

This works for me:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype='str')
```

If you want to be more selective in your columns or use the str instance directly:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fp, dtype={"date":str})
```

The Pandas docs explain in more detail:

> dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, optional
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} > Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not > interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

(from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)